# Assigning a value to a pointer inside a function

Tags: c, string, binary, hex

Okay, so I have a question, I guess about C strings. Below is my modification to some code (given in an answer to a previous stackoverflow question!), with the function call and the output. The function converts an input hex number (of length 8) to a binary number (of length 32).

```
void htoi(const char *ptr, char *binAddr) {
char value[32] = "";
char ch = *ptr;
int i;
const char* quads[] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101",
                     "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
                     "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"};

while (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
    ch = *(++ptr);

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        strncat(value, quads[ch - '0'], 4);
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        strncat(value, quads[10 + ch - 'A'], 4);
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        strncat(value, quads[10 + ch - 'a'], 4);

    ch = *(++ptr);
    printf("%s\n", value);
}

*binAddr = *value;
}
```

Here is my function call:

```
char line[11], hexAddr[8], binAddr[32];
htoi(hexAddr, binAddr);
printf("%s\n", binAddr);
```

Here is the output (when input with 001133c0):

0000

00000000

000000000001

0000000000010001

00000000000100010011

000000000001000100110011

0000000000010001001100111100

00000000000100010011001111000000

0���

The last line (with the special characters) is the printf(binAddr) in the main function above. It is clear from the printf statements inside the function that the binary code is being constructed correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
*binAddr = *value;
```

What do you think it does?  Both arguments, before the asterisks are applied, refer to character arrays, or pointers to char.  So when dereferenced, they refer to one char each.  So this statement assigns the first char in binAddr equal to the first char in value, whereas presumably you wanted to return the whole string.

Comment: OK, then be sure to allocate 33 chars, not 32, for your 32-character string.

Answer (score 1):

You're not leaving room for (or inserting) the null that terminates the value array, which needs to be at least 33 chars long.

Answer (score 0):

you are constructing a character string with characters '0' and '1'.  what you need to create is a sequence of BYTES. you will need to take an unsigned int or a an equivalent 64-bit type and set the bits according to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
*binAddr = *value;
```

This part of the function does not make any sense.  *binAddr is passed into the function and will be out of scope once the function ends.  You need to save the value you meant to save in *binAddr in a global variable or something else that won't go out of scope.

The fact that you do have a global binAddr, is also confusing the issue since it is being hidden by the local binAddr.

Comment: Surely global variables are not the solution to this person's problem!